# @ngrx/store-devtools: instrumentStore() returns an array of objects instead of providers

Tags: typescript, angular, webpack, ngrx

I'm working on a Angular 2 project using this seed: [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) and I'm also using @ngrx/store & [@ngrx/store-devtools](https://github.com/ngrx/store-devtools).

During bootstraping, the application throws an error :

**`zone.js:260 - Uncaught Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [object Object]`**

Here is how I setting up @ngrx with the seed :

#### Add packages to `vendor.browser.ts`

```
// ngrx
import '@ngrx/core';
import '@ngrx/store';
import 'ngrx-store-router';

if ('production' === ENV) {
  // Production


} else {
  // Development
  require('angular2-hmr');
  require('@ngrx/store-devtools');
  require('@ngrx/store-log-monitor');

}
```

#### Add providers for angular 2 (`browser-providers.ts`)

```
// @ngrx/store
import { provideStore } from '@ngrx/store';
// @ngrx/devtools
import { instrumentStore } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { useLogMonitor } from '@ngrx/store-log-monitor';
// link angular's router with ngrx/sotre
import { routerMiddleware } from 'ngrx-store-router';
// custom data for ngrx
import { REDUCERS, initialState } from '../app/shared/redux';

export const APPLICATION_PROVIDERS = [
  // awesome redux implementation for angular
  provideStore(REDUCERS, initialState),
  instrumentStore({
    monitor: useLogMonitor({
      visible: true,
      position: 'right'
    })
  }),

  // link angular's router with ngrx/sotre
  routerMiddleware,

  //...
];
```

#### Add the monitor to my app template

`<ngrx-store-log-monitor toggleCommand="ctrl-h" positionCommand="ctrl-m"></ngrx-store-log-monitor>`.

---

Simple.

But when I `console.log` what `instrumentStore()` returns, I get an array of objects. But Angular needs and array of Providers.

Here are the versions of my packages:

- Angular2: rc3
- @ngrx/core: 1.0.1
- @ngrx/store: 1.5.0
- @ngrx/store-devtools: 2.0.0-beta1
- @ngrx/store-log-monitor: 2.0.0-beta1

If it's an issue, I'll report in on the Github. But I'm not sure to set up everything right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was simple.
I've upgraded `@ngrx/store` to version 2 (2.0.1) and it works.